# Display MYSQL results in html table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

Im not sure if a similar question has been asked before, but here goes anyway. (I did do a search and found nothing relating to my question).

I am developing a website in which videos are played using the HTML5 video player. I have a connection to my database, a "watch" page that pulls all the correct data using a variable linked to the id (watch.php?v=1). I would like to have an index page where the most recent videos are pulled. They are ordered by the column "id" and everything works when I try and pull one result from the query. How would I go about getting multiple values? Here is my php code (server details hidden):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("HIDDEN", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN");
$sql = "
       SELECT id, title, imgsrc, description
       FROM videos
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 2
";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$video = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

And here is my HTML code for the table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><h2><? echo $video['title']; ?></h2></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

That isn't the full code, but once I know the procedure I can apply it where needed!

I'm quite new to php and mysql, I can connect to databases but that's about it so a full walkthrough about what does what would be great!

Many Thanks,

James Wassall

Comment: It seems to me that this is a widely discussed issue !?!?!

Comment: just loop through the results and add a new row for each record

Comment: @gbestard I don't know how to do that.. hence my reason for asking.

Comment: This is very fundamental and you are by your own admission new.  A tutorial to learn basic skills might be a good investment of time and effort.

Comment: @DanBracuk I could do with spending some time learning mysql and php properly but I don't use databases very often unless necessary so most of the time I look to the internet for solutions and to fill in the gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate in for or while loop by calling `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`:

```
<table>

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("HIDDEN", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN", "HIDDEN");
$sql = "
   SELECT id, title, imgsrc, description
   FROM videos
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 2
";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($video = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>

<tr>
<td><h2><? echo $video['title']; ?></h2></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>

</table>
```

Note that you should consider checking error statements, null controls etc.

Comment: Had to modify this slightly but does everything I need! Many Thanks to everyone else for their answers too but this answer shows the initial code too.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($video = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
    <tr>
     <td><h2><?php echo $video['title']; ?></h2></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call mysqli_fetch_array, only one row is fetched.

You need to do something like

```
while ($video = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // output $video['title']
}
```

(according to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        <table>
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

            <tr>
                <td><h2><? echo $row['title']; ?></h2></td>
                <td><h2><? echo $row['description']; ?></h2></td>
            </tr>

        <?php } ?>
        </table>
```